# SSH Screen Ignoring CTRL

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, gnu-screen

When I SSH into a particular server and launch `screen`, it ignores my `CTRL+a` key combo.  Instead of `CTRL+a c` creating a new screen window, it instead acts as if I had just typed `c`.  Other key combos fail in a similar way.

I've tried launching screen using `screen -e ^jj` to bind to `j` instead of `a`, but I still get the same result as above.

I tried adding a `.screenrc` file to my homedir that I know works on other machines, but it has no impact.

I also tried launch a zsh shell instead of bash.

Any ideas where to start to try and fix this?  This basically renders screen unusable.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you type Ctrl-V Ctrl-A? (Incidentally, I have `escape ^@^@` in my `.screenrc`; it lets me use Ctrl-space as my command key, which I find is very easy to use.)

Comment: `Ctrl-V Ctrl-A` gives me a `^A`

Comment: Ok, that tells you that `screen` isn't recognizing Ctrl-A.  Check for `$HOME/.screenrc`, `/etc/screenrc`, and the `$SYSSCREENRC` and `$SCREENRC` environment variables, and look for an `escape` command; see the "FILES" section of `man screen`. (But that doesn't explain why `-e ^jj` didn't work.)

Comment: Found it! `/etc/screenrc` contained `escape \`e`.  Thanks for your help! If you'd like to submit an answer I'll accept it. I no longer want to throw my laptop out a window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` reads commands from several configuration files during startup, as described in the FILES section of the man page or the [Customizing Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Startup-Files) section of the [User's Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) (also available, if it's installed, by typing `info screen`).

The files read are:

- The file named by the `$SYSSCREENRC` environment variable (this may or may not be enabled)
- `/etc/screenrc`
- The file named by the `$SCREENRC` environment variable`
- `$HOME/.screenrc`

(These interact and are searched in various ways that I don't entirely understand.)

In your particular case, based on the comments, the system on which you're running `screen` happens to have a `/etc/screenrc` file that contains an `escape` command that overrides the default.

A digression: in my own `$HOME/.screenrc` I have:

```
escape ^@^@
```

This sets the escape character to the null character, which can be entered by typing <kbd>Ctrl-space</kbd>. I find it easier to type, and less likely to conflict with other uses, than the default <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>. The only conflict I run into is the Emac `set-mark-command` function, and for that it's easy enough to type it twice.